# Multiple combinations from single set

Tags: math, combinations

suppose I have a single set of 9 elements `{A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I}` and that I need to create 3 groups of 3 elements each. I know that I can do:

`9C3 * 6C3 * 3C3` and that is 1680 different combinations but in those combinations may appear `{{A, B, C}, {D, E, F}, {G, H, I}`} and `{{D, E, F}, {G, H, I}, {A, B, C}}`.

I need to do this in MathLab but the formula to calculate this is fine.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each triplet of 3-element sets van be organized in 3! = 6 ways: ABC, ACB, BAC, BCA, CAB and CBA, which are equivilent.
So divide your initial result (was it 1680?), by 6.

If the nine individual elements are not guaranteed to all be distinct, then you need to account for that as well.